# How to unmelt a completely melted table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have this dataframe `df` which I have melted and then using pd.pivot_table I am able to get the table structure back at least looking at the rows it seems so - but the indexes become `MultiIndex` type - is there a way to change to back to `RangeIndex` as it was in the original `df`

Here are the steps

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Bob', 'John', 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Alex', 'Tom'], 
                   'Math': ['A+', 'B', 'A', 'F', 'D', 'C'], 
                   'Mental Math': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'B'], 
                   'English': ['C', 'B', 'B', 'A+', 'F', 'A'],
                   'Bengali': ['C', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A+', 'B'],
                   'Age': [13, 16, 16, 15, 15, 13]})
>>> print(df)
    Name Math Mental Math English Bengali  Age
0   Bob   A+           A       C       C   13
1  John    B           A       B       C   16
2   Foo    A           B       B       A   16
3   Bar    F           C      A+       B   15
4  Alex    D           E       F      A+   15
5   Tom    C           B       A       B   13

>>> d = df.melt(var_name='Column', value_name='Value')
>>> print(d)

          Column Value
0          Name   Bob
1          Name  John
2          Name   Foo
3          Name   Bar
4          Name  Alex
5          Name   Tom
6          Math    A+
7          Math     B
8          Math     A
9          Math     F
10         Math     D
11         Math     C
12  Mental Math     A
13  Mental Math     A
14  Mental Math     B
15  Mental Math     C
16  Mental Math     E
17  Mental Math     B
18      English     C
19      English     B
20      English     B
21      English    A+
22      English     F
23      English     A
24      Bengali     C
25      Bengali     C
26      Bengali     A
27      Bengali     B
28      Bengali    A+
29      Bengali     B
30          Age    13
31          Age    16
32          Age    16
33          Age    15
34          Age    15
35          Age    13
```

Is it possible to get back to the original table as in the original indexes
Using `pandas.pivot_table` tried to return to the original dataframe but if you see the index now has become a MultiIndex type

```
>>> df_back = pd.pivot_table(data = d, index=['Name','Age'], columns=['Column'], aggfunc=''.join, margins=False)

>>> print(df_back)

             Value                         
Column   Bengali English Math Mental Math
Name Age                                 
Alex 15       A+       F    D           E
Bar  15        B      A+    F           C
Bob  13        C       C   A+           A
Foo  16        A       B    A           B
John 16        C       B    B           A
Tom  13        B       A    C           B

>>> print(df_back.index)

MultiIndex([('Alex', 15),
            ( 'Bar', 15),
            ( 'Bob', 13),
            ( 'Foo', 16),
            ('John', 16),
            ( 'Tom', 13)],
           names=['Name', 'Age'])

>>> print(df.index)

RangeIndex(start=0, stop=6, step=1)
```

Comment: You omitted one step here, your `melt` did not leave `Name` or `Age` as columns.

Answer (score 0):

As @mozway said your code does not work, some steps must be missing

But to go from d to df you can use `unstack`. You need a unique index for this to work hence this is where `'count'` column comes in

```
(d.assign(count = np.arange(len(d))%6)
    .set_index(['count','Column'])
    .unstack(level=1)
    .reset_index(drop = True)
    .droplevel(level = 0, axis=1)
)
```

output

```
      Age  Bengali    English    Math    Mental Math    Name
--  -----  ---------  ---------  ------  -------------  ------
 0     13  C          C          A+      A              Bob
 1     16  C          B          B       A              John
 2     16  A          B          A       B              Foo
 3     15  B          A+         F       C              Bar
 4     15  A+         F          D       E              Alex
 5     13  B          A          C       B              Tom
```